# Password Encryption

Tags: java, database

I have stored user passwords in an encrypted format in my database. However, now when user wants to login and tries to put their original password the code always compares the entered (original) password with the encrypted version stored in the database, leading to a failed login.

Please tell me how to compare the entered (original) password with the encrypted password stored in the database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should almost certainly be [*hashing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash) the password rather than using reversible encryption. You may need to do this with a [*salt*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) too... in which case the correct steps are:

- Find the salt that was used when originally hashing the password (this will generally be stored with the hashed password).
- Hash the password entered by the user using that salt.
- Compare the two hashes - if they're equal, the user (almost certainly) entered the right password.

Note the difference between the when you store the hashed password to start with, when you generate a *random* salt, and when you verify the stored hash, when you use the *stored* salt.

Comment: actually i have used MD5 for encryption of password....as MD5 is one way process i guess....please tell me what will be the other technique..???

Comment: @Smith: I'd advise using something stronger than MD5 these days, but that's a hash. I'm not sure what you mean by "the other technique" - I'm suggesting you *don't* use a reversible encryption algorithm; something like MD5 but stronger (e.g. SHA-256) would be fine.

Comment: @Smith: Using MD5 means you **hashed** the password, you didn't encrypt it. Now, all these people are telling you to rehash **with same method (MD5)** the password user provides and then compare this to what you have stored.

Comment: Ideally, you should do something better than SHA-256.  SHA-256 is secure enough, but it's too fast to block brute-force.  Use multi-round SHA-256 (something like 1000 iterations) or use PKDBF2 or bcrypt (or maybe scrypt, depending on your view of the algorithm)

Answer (score 3):

Dont encrypt  the Password! just hash it (MD5/SHA1/bcrypt) and save the hash value which you compare then with the hash value of each password the user enters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encrypt the entered password, then compare the encrypted entered password with the encrypted stored password.

Comment: The fact that this answer needs to exist makes me a sad developer.  +1 for saying it better than I could.

Comment: how can i entered encrypted password??i want to entered my original password because how can i know what is encrypted password for my original??????????

Comment: This won't work. How do you compare two different ciphers of the same string? The result of cipher('a') will not be equal to result of cipher('a') in the next call if it is a reasonable encryption.

Comment: @Smith: There's no need for all those question marks. Presumably the user has entered their username as well as the password, right? So you can look up the hashed password in your database based on the username. Then compare that with the hashed version of the password just entered by the user.

Answer (score 1):

obviously, it fails. You have to encrypt the original password every time when you want to validate against the database.

Comment: @Richard Gadsden: Because serious encryption uses a different initialization vector IV in each call to the `encrypt`-function. This will result in different cypher text for the same plain text. So `encrypt("plain",myKey,IV1)!=encrypt("plain",myKey,IV2)`. You do not want the same cipher text generated for the same plain text, because this would be easy to use for crypt analysis. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector

Comment: @Michael Konietzka But if you're storing passwords in the db, then you store the IV as a salt, and you put the same IV back in each time. In fact, that's the point.

Comment: @Richard Gadsden: When you use the same IV for encryption again, you can check equity, that is right. Therefore I'd like to remove my "-1", but that is not possible, because my vote is too old.

Answer (score 0):

If you required the dynamic create java password, everytime its is dynamically generated,

Link,

http://brigitzblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/java-dynamic-password-generation.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to decrypt the stored password and check for equality with the entered password.

Comment: Wasn't me, but the point is that you shouldn't be using reversible encryption in the first place - indeed, the user was using MD5.

Comment: @Richard Gadsden: The OP mentioned "encryption", not "hash", so the password has to be decrypt or encrypt. Of course the "should be" is to hash the password, but there are scenarios, where user passwords are encrypted instead of hashed.