# PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

```
public UserBean authenticate(String username,String password){
    PostGresDAO pg=new PostGresDAO();   //creates new connection
    Connection conn=pg.getConnecion();  //return connection object
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    String query="select password,name from scg_users where username=?";
    UserBean ub=null;
    boolean authenticated=false;
    try{
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, username);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();

        if(rs!=null){

            authenticated=password.equals(rs.getString(1));  //exception raised here
            if(authenticated){
                ub=new UserBean();
                ub.setUser(rs.getString(2));
                ub.setUsername(username);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ub;
}
```

I am using this code for authenticating a user. The username and password are extracted from the request parameter and passed onto this method for authentication. But it throws a:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.
```

Please advice.

Comment: Please, please, please don't store passwords in plain text. Salt them and hash them with a decent one-way hash. Even better, don't write the user authentication code yourself, use existing tested code by authenticating with a suitable library or container, or via a service like SASL with CRAM-MD5 challenge-response, or with Kerberos. That way you never even need to see the user's password at all. See eg http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm for passwords.

Comment: Since you're using Java, you should look into [`JSSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html), [`Java GSS`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2853.txt), or [`Java SASL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/sasl/sasl-refguide.html). Don't write your own authentication scheme.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322055/password-encryption

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks a lottttt for guiding me in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The error is telling you *exactly* what's wrong - you're not calling `next()` on your ResultSet to get to the first row of the results.

This line:

```
if(rs!=null)
```

is pointless as far as I know; I don't believe `executeQuery` will ever return null. If there's a problem in your query, an exception will be thrown. If there are no results, it will return an empty result set. To see if there's a row, you should call `next()` and check the return value:

```
if (rs.next())
```

Additionally:

- Catching an exception and just printing the stack trace without rethrowing is *almost* always the wrong approach
- Your code suggests that you're storing passwords in plain text. Please don't. Really, really don't.

Comment: Just to note that isBeforeFirst will return  true if the cursor is before the first row, which essentially means that you have a result set.However, isBeforeFirst will not point the cursor at the first row. Even if your result set is only 1 row (e.g. you have a LIMIT 1 query), you still need to use next(), unfortunately, because in my opinion that implies a collection, not a single result.

Answer (score 4):

Because I got the message even when I called `next()` on `resultSet` I'll tell my solution.

The solution is NOT to call `resultSet.get*` on your `resultSet` if it's empty. So do a check `if(resultSet.next()){ ...`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if(rs!=null)
```

You need to check for

```
if(rs.next())
```

This will return the first row, if there are any matching rows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have `resultSet.next()` in debugger Inline Watches :)

It was the case for me;
So my check `if (resultSet.next())` returns true but when I go inside the if block, the next() is called again and then there is no data so I got the same error message